# mysql error code 1292 truncated incorrect double value '05:00:00' when creating a table. No error if selecting the data only

Tags: mysql

When I run the following code I get error message: "mysql error code 1292 truncated incorrect double value '05:00:00'" If I run a select query instead of create table it returns the information with no error message. Trying to create a table to filter further.

```
create table seasons
            select id, ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, start_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_name, end_station_id, 
            member_casual, month, ride_length, 
            case
            when hour(started_at) between '05:00:00' and '11:59:59' then "morning"
            when hour(started_at) between '12:00:00' and '17:59:59' then "afternoon"
            when hour(started_at) between '18:00:00' and '23:59:59' then "evening"
            when hour(started_at) between '00:00:00' and '04:59:59' then "late_night" end as time_of_day,
            case
            when month in ("12", "1", "2") then "winter"
            when month in ("3", "4", "5") then "spring"
            when month in ("6", "7", "8") then "summer"
            when month in ("9", "10", "11") then "fall" end as season,
            case
            when hour(started_at) between '00:00:00' and '00:59:59' then "12_1AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '01:00:00' and '1:59:59' then "1_2AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '02:00:00' and '02:59:59' then "2_3AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '03:00:00' and '03:59:59' then "3_4AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '04:00:00' and '04:59:59' then "4_5AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '05:00:00' and '05:59:59' then "5_6AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '06:00:00' and '06:59:59' then "6_7AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '07:00:00' and '07:59:59' then "7_8AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '08:00:00' and '08:59:59' then "8_9AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '09:00:00' and '09:59:59' then "9_10AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '10:00:00' and '10:59:59' then "10_11AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '11:00:00' and '11:59:59' then "11_12AM"
            when hour(started_at) between '12:00:00' and '12:59:59' then "12_1PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '13:00:00' and '13:59:59' then "1_2PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '14:00:00' and '14:59:59' then "2_3PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '15:00:00' and '15:59:59' then "3_4PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '16:00:00' and '16:59:59' then "4_5PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '17:00:00' and '17:59:59' then "5_6PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '18:00:00' and '18:59:59' then "6_7PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '19:00:00' and '19:59:59' then "7_8PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '20:00:00' and '20:59:59' then "8_9PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '21:00:00' and '21:59:59' then "9_10PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '22:00:00' and '22:59:59' then "10_11PM"
            when hour(started_at) between '23:00:00' and '23:59:59' then "11_12PM" end as hour
        from length_of_rides;
```

Comment: Would not `hour(started_at) between '05:00:00' and '11:59:59'` instead be: `hour(started_at) between 5 and 11`? ... same for the others using `hour`.

Comment: *`when hour(started_at) between '05:00:00' and '11:59:59' then "morning"`* - in this expression the output of [HOUR() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) sets numeric (double-precision) context for the whole expression. So string (not time!) value `'05:00:00'` should be converted to according datatype. Use [TIME() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) instead.